# Faster Regex other than .+ to match whole string

Tags: regex, string

I need to match a whole string using a regex, I know that a regex isn't the best soloution to return the whole string but the software I am using is restricted to regexes.

A typical string would be a whole page of HTML from a webpage, sometimes it is necessary to use a regex to match the whole string which would be accomplished with any of the following

```
.+
^.+$
\A.+\Z
[\S\s]*
```

they all take between 10 - 13 ms which seems really slow considering I just want to get the the whole string by using a regex, is there any key word or special regex function  I can use to match the entire string without checking, as obviously the 4 examples I have given above are too slow

Comment: how long is your string and what language you using?

Comment: Use atomic grouping (http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html), or possessive quantifiers (http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html).

Comment: String is approximately 148,000 characters, the regexes are used to scrape websites, although the regexes are handles by a C# application, there is no way to use any other C# functionality other than what could be put inside a regex unfortunately,

Comment: Why are you passing it through a regex in the first place? Is it possible to skip that step?

Comment: unfortunately its not possible to skip the regex step. We use a tool to plan the traversal of a site by building regexes. somes we need to capture the whole page in which case we are using .+ but this is slow, These regexes are handled by a C# application, but there is no way for us to using any c# logic other than regexes. I know one answer would be to rewrite all our in house software, but I'm thinking of something to tide us over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .NET regex engine, you can use [atomic groupings](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html) to enhance performance.

E.g. `^(?s)(?>.+)$`, or just `(?s)(?>.+)`.

Have a look at [this video](http://regexhero.net/videos/12/optimizing-for-performance).

Comment: I think atomic grouping is not relevant here. `.+` never backtracks anyway. `^(?>.+)$` could have backtracking, but the regex should be run in `SingleLine` mode anyway, which makes `.` matches any character without exception and will reach the end of string.

Comment: Yeah, I added an inline `s` option.

Comment: Regardless, I think the atomic grouping is useless, since a match will be found anyway.